# How to embed JS file in Magento page?

Tags: page-layouts

I have been working in the recovery of a hacked Magento 1.9 installation, 
this site was destroyed and I managed to recover the database and make it work again with an updated version of the template/theme that was used originally (Milano).

There is a page, "store locator" that uses a external JS file that is called scriptstorelocator.js

This file was part of the old hacked filesystem, Which I have a backup, I copied the file to the same folder where it used to be to the new installation, but does not work. Somehow seems that the
JS file is not loaded.

Not sure I have placed the file in the wrong folder:

I have stored it public_html/skin/frontend/default/milano/js/

or Im doing something wrong in the page settings?

I have tried to paste the JS inside the HTML editor (very naive) and it didnt work, is there a way to bypass this?

Thanks guys

I attach this images that show the settings:

[image: settings snapshot 2]

[image: Page layout snapshot]

**UPDATE**

Finally I managed to insert the JS file in the header using

```
       <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptstorelocator.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"></script>]]>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: what hapen My answer not help you??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you had write `skin_js` then you need to put js file in ,

`skin/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/js` in this folder you can put your js.

Hope This will help you

Comment: for completeness: check that the package/theme are what you think in 'System > Configuration > (General) Design'

Comment: yes your theme which you are using .yes  you will get detail in 'system->config.->design'

Comment: The package is default and the theme Milano, the JS folder is in the folder /skin/frontend/default/milano/js/ but it doesnt pick up.

Comment: replace with those name in my answer your package with default and theme with Milano

Comment: I have tried nothing happens. I checked the browser console that it gives a error "BASE_URL is not defined" could this be related?

Comment: yes of course check why you get this error

Comment: flush js and css cache from admin once and try again

Comment: I have flushed all cache and no results... seems that Im on the wrong folder or something, the files are there, but Magento doesnt use them. 
I suspect that the error has something to do, but all other pages and things are working fine.

Comment: Add this file in `base/default` instead `default/milano`  your files always pick from that place

Comment: It did not work. Is there another way to do this you can recommend me?

Comment: put js in your root js folder and write below syntax  `<reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>folder/file.js</script></action>
    </reference>`

Comment: <![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/js/scriptstorelocator.js"></script><script type="text/javascript"></script>]]>

made it :) thanks.